# Do you say Tachanun at a Pidyon HaBen?

Tags: halacha, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer, pidyon-haben

Most Pidyon HaBen's take place in the afternoon. Do you say Tachanun at Mincha which is immediately preceding a Pidyon HaBen? (sources)

Comment: Might it depend on whether the _pidyon_ is around the same time/place as the _t'fila_?

Comment: It might. I do not know. My question is regarding a Mincha immediately preceding a Pidyon.

Comment: I'm guessing yes. A seudat mitzva doesn't make it a yom tov (eg a siyum).

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect mincha is any different from shacharit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.mevaseret.org/mmy/searchshiurim.php?shiur=391

> If the Pidyon Haben and its festive meal will take place immediately
>   after davening, Tachanun is not recited (Ishai Yisrael 25:26 quoting
>   Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach).

However the [Mishnas Yehoshua](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51576&st=&pgnum=356&hilite=) brings in the name of the Sova Semochos that you do say Tachanun at a Pidyon HaBen